# If td has value "No" add class to different td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code:

```
<td class="bedrag">
    #_ATT{Factuur bedrag}
</td>
<td class="paid">
    #_ATT{Betaald}{Ja|Nee}
</td>
```

In the `td paid` the option can be given for Yes or No. I would like change the background of `bedrag` depending on what was chosen in the `td paid`. I figured the best way to go was to `addClass` using Javascript. So I googled around for a while and found this piece of code:

```
jQuery('a:contains("Sponsored")').closest('.post-item').addClass('sponz');
```

I changed it to fit my needs:

```
$('.paid:contains("Nee")').closest('.bedrag').addClass('sponz');
```

But that didn't work. So I tried the following code:

```
$('.paid:contains("Nee")').addClass('sponz');
```

This adds the class `sponz` to the td `paid`. But I want to add it to `bedrag`. So I then tried this:

```
('.bedrag:has(.paid:contains("Nee"))').addClass('sponz');
```

But this also didn't work.

Anyone know how to get this code working so that it will add `sponz` the the `td bedrag` when a user selects the option `Nee`? thanks in advance!

Comment: SO you say DIV, but you mean TD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`closest()` isn't quite what you need as that looks for parents. `.bedrag` is a sibling of `.paid`, so you need to use `prev()` instead:

```js
$('.paid:contains("Nee")').prev('.bedrag').addClass('sponz');
```

```css
.sponz { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="bedrag">bedrag 1</td>
    <td class="paid">Nee</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bedrag">bedrag 2</td>
    <td class="paid">Ja</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="bedrag">bedrag 3</td>
    <td class="paid">Nee</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I'll Accept your answer when I can!

Comment: Safer to swap `.prev` for `.siblings` for a more robust approach incase the html isn't exact?

Comment: Possible, but the implication here is that the elements are all on the same row of the table. If you did want to use `siblings()`, then you'd probably need to combine it with `:first`.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do an if?

```
if ($('.paid:contains("Nee")').length !== 0) { // there's at least an element
   // add class to the right element
}
```